# How can a new data be added to firebase without the post keys?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I use the following code to add new data to firebase.

```
var postData = {
            NSN: NSN,
            ProductName: ProductName,

            AssociatedContractNumber: AssociatedContractNumber,
            ItemQuantity: ItemQuantity,
            viewable_by: uid,
        };

        InventoryID = firebase.database().ref().child('Posts').push().key;

        var updates = {};
        updates['/Businesses/' + uid + '/Inventory/' + InventoryID] = postData;
```

what i want to do is to create a list of NSNs in child "NSN" without the uniquely generated post ids. But all the attempt to add just the NSN to child NSN keeps replace the old with the new NSN. so instead of something like 10 different NSNs i only got 1 which is the most recent one added. 
I used this code initially

```
var postNSN = {
            NSN: NSN,
         };
       updates['/Businesses/' + uid + '/National_Stock_Numbers/' + NSN] = postNSN;
```

the above only replaces the existing number with the new one instead of adding the new one

I also tried this

```
  var NSNref = database.ref('/Businesses/' + uid + '/NSNs/')
  NSNref.set({
            NSN: NSN,
        })
```

but nothing happens. How can I add a new NSN to child NSNs without the uniquely generated keys?

Answer (score 1):

Just use `push()`

Say if you had and NSN object like

```
var NSN = { ... }
firebase.database().ref().child('Posts').push(NSN);
```

Doing this will always push the item to the end of your NSN array and firebase will take care creating unique key at the time of pushing.

Remember firebase don't know about arrays it only knows about objects.

Comment: .push() generates a key for every post. How can post without generating the key

Comment: How should your final data model look like can you share it?