# How to loop through each firebase database child with python?

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this firebase data structure

[image]

I want to print all the keys under the firebase generated keys (i.e from 3030-00-809-7702 to newNSN) so I use this code

```
Inventory = db.child("Inventories").get()
for business in Inventory.each():
businessid = business.key()
productdb = db.child("Inventories").child(businessid).get()


for product in productdb.each():
    productid = product.key()
print(businessid)
print(productid)
```

but I what I get is this

[image]

so only the last keys are being printed instead of all the keys. What am I doing wrongly and how can I get it to print all the keys ?

Comment: I notice that you keep using this Pyrebase library instead of the official one... Any reason why?
 https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python/firebase_admin.db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just print the value at the current tree to get the whole thing

```
inventory = db.child("Inventories").get()
for business in inventory.each():
    print(business.val())
```

Or you go iterate it, which is really inefficient to request N items from Firebase for N children.

```
inventorydb = db.child("Inventories")
for businessid in inventorydb.shallow().get().each():
    productdb = inventory.child(businessid)
    # print the ids
    print([id for id in productdb.shallow().get()])
```

Comment: the reason why I wanted just the NSN numbers for each child is so that I can put all of them in an array. I want to collect about a thousand NSN numbers and put them in an array.

Comment: Okay, well, still. Heavily nested data isn't optimal in Firebase query model

Comment: Yea, I know that the deep nesting is a potential problem. that's why I was trying implement a different method and could not figure out how to do this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46146691/how-can-a-new-data-be-added-to-firebase-without-the-post-keys

Comment: If you want to push a known name without overriding it,  you'll need to create an incremental type of key. I don't have any examples of that though