# Python - Complex Query in Google Firebase

Tags: python, python-3.x, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a database which is shown in below

[image]

I want to show only the `full_names` in order. I want that output:

```
Alan Turing
Alan Turing
Alan Turing
Alan Turing
Alan Turing
```

I tried with this code below but it shows the user names.

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import db

# Fetch the service account key JSON file contents
cred = credentials.Certificate('BLABLA.json')
# Initialize the app with a service account, granting admin privileges
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
    'databaseURL': 'https://BLABLA.firebaseio.com/'
})

ref = db.reference('users')
snapshot = ref.order_by_child('full_name').get()
for key in snapshot:
    print(key)
```

The output is:

```
alanisawesom
alanisawesome
alanisawesomee
alanisawesomeee
alanisawesomeeee
```

Where is my fault? Can you fix it?

**EDIT: My Rules in Firebase is:**

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      ".indexOn": ["date_of_birth", "full_name"]
    },
    ".read": "true",
    ".write": "true"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query tells the database to return the nodes under `users` ordered by their `full_name` property. But Firebase still returns the full nodes, not just the property you told it to order on.

To only display the `full_name` of each node, you need to get that property from each child node in the result. Something like this:

```
ref = db.reference('users')
snapshot = ref.order_by_child('full_name').get()
for user in snapshot.each():
    print(user.child("full_name").val())
```

I'm not a Pythonista, so I looked here for help on syntax: [How to loop through each firebase database child with python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46147443/how-to-loop-through-each-firebase-database-child-with-python)

Comment: I didn't find the correct syntax on your shared link, can you give exact solution?

Comment: I tried to give you the exact code in my question. If that doesn't work for you, can you tell what happens when you run it?

Comment: AttributeError: 'collections.OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'each'

Comment: if I delete ".each()"; it shows "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'child'"