# deleting a single dictionary from Fire-base real time database (python3)

Tags: python-3.x, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, filter

Data in fire-base database is as below:

[image]

my intention is to interact with a single dictionary at a time, such as delete it from fire-base or update it. To do this i have to filter through the database with multiple filters such as by **home_team** and **away_team**

**edit**

I have been successful in filtering through the data to the specific dictionary i would like to remove. ps. add rules to firebase as followed here: [adding rules to firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55144753/python-complex-query-in-google-firebase)

current code is as below:

```
import pyrebase

# firebase configuration
########################
config = {
    ...
}

firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
db = firebase.database()

games = db.child("basketball").order_by_key().order_by_child("home_team").equal_to("Singapore Slingers").get()
print(games.val())  # success 

# now to delete 
db.child("basketball").order_by_key().order_by_child("home_team").equal_to("Singapore Slingers").remove()  # this clears the entire database even though i have filtered to the database i would like to remove
```

**The expected result** would be to delete the game whose home_team == 'Singapore Slingers' && away_team == 'CLS Knights Surabaya' from firebase real time database

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Query based on multiple where clauses in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase)

Comment: @AndréKool i had a look at that and as a result i tried .orderByChild('home_team').equalTo('Singapore Slingers') to no success. If you would know a better way to work with .orderByChild() that i cant that'd be great

Comment: Have made progress and added them as edits to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,

found the answer myself,

First i installed pyrebase4 `pip install pyrebase4`, find out more on this at [pyrebase4 @ GitHub](https://github.com/nhorvath/Pyrebase4).

Next i edited rules @ Fire-base as:

```
{
"rules": {
    "basketball" : {
          ".indexOn": ["home_team", "away_team"]
        },
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

my working code then sits as:

```
import pyrebase

# firebase configuration
########################

config = {
    ...
}

firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
db = firebase.database()

# game filter
games = db.child("basketball").order_by_child("home_team").equal_to("Singapore Slingers").order_by_child("away_team").equal_to("CLS Knights Surabaya").get().val()

# Gēmu o korosu
for game in games:
    db.child("basketball").child(game).remove()
# works like a charm
```